# getting a internal server error on redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess

My old page url looks like this

`https://blabla.com/us/sample-data/us/`

my new url looks like this

`https://blabla.com/us/data/sample/us/`

I added this into my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Redirect 301 ^sample-data/us/ /data/sample/us/ [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

but i'm getting a `internal server error`

the 1st `us` in the url is dynamic depending on country user is from. and the 2nd `us` is the countries sample data. which is a list of 10 countries at the moment. could be more.

i tried

`RewriteRule ^sample-data/us/ /data/sample/us/ [L,R=301,NC]`

but no luck either. it redirects too

`https://blabla.com/data/sample/us/` missing the 1st  `/us/`

how do get this redirect working? Thanks

Comment: _“the 1st us in the url is dynamic depending on country user is from”_ - and where exactly does that part get handled? Is that a _physical_ directory, and the .htaccess is located in there? (If not, then what you have shown makes rather little sense to begin with, if this was on the root level, then `^sample-data/us/` should not have matched in the first place.)

Comment: no the 1st `us` is not a physical directory, its a url created instead of having `?country=us`. `https://blabla.com`, points to the root level

Comment: Then I don’t see how `RewriteRule ^sample-data/us/` could ever match in the first place - you anchored that pattern at the beginning, but the requested URL path does _not_ start with `sample-data/…`, but it is actually `us/sample-data/us/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> Redirect 301 ^sample-data/us/ /data/sample/us/ [NC,L]
> </IfModule>
> ```
>
> but i'm getting a internal server error

Because that directive is syntactically invalid. The `[NC,L]` argument is a parameter belonging to the mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` directive. `Redirect` is a mod_alias directive - there is no such "flags" parameter with the `Redirect` directive.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^sample-data/us/ /data/sample/us/ [L,R=301,NC]
> ```
>
> but no luck either. it redirects too
>
> `https://blabla.com/data/sample/us/` missing the 1st `/us/`

You appear to be missing the 1st `/us/` (virtual path segment) from your directives, so I don't see how this is redirecting at all (unless you are seeing a cached response, or *something else* is performing the redirect)? This `.htaccess` file is presumably in the document root and you are presumably requesting the URL `/us/sample-data/us/` and the first `/us/` is virtual - so the directive above cannot possibly do anything?

If the first path segment is variable and you need to redirect to the same path segment and assuming this consists of two lowercase a-z letters then try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/sample-data/us/ /$1/data/sample/us/ [R=302,L]
```

But what about the 2nd `/us/` - is that not also variable? Should the 1st and 2nd instance of `/XX/` (two letters) be the same?

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues. You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

I've removed the `NC` flag - should this really be a case-insensitive match?

Note that if you have existing directives in your `.htaccess` file then the order is important. Generally, external redirects need to go near the top, certainly before your *front-controller*.